# Proof verification (basic calculus)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification, asymptotics

Let $t\in(0,1)$, $c>0$ an arbitrary constant and  $a_n$ a positive real sequence such that $a_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. I want to show that for every $n$ suficiently large there is $c'>0$ satisfying
$$t^{c a_n}\leq a_n^{-c'}.$$

Can this $c'>0$ made arbitrarily large?

**My proof**

The following equivalence holds $$t^{c a_n}\leq a_n^{-c'}\iff ca_n\ln t\leq -c'\ln a_n\iff -c\frac{a_n}{\ln a_n}\ln t\geq c'.$$

As $a_n/\ln a_n\to\infty$, we can always take $c'>0:-c\ln t\geq c'$ for $n$ large enough so that $a_n/\ln a_n\geq 1$, because then
$$-c\frac{a_n}{\ln a_n}\ln t\geq -c\ln t\geq c'\implies t^{c a_n}\leq a_n^{-c'}.$$

This $c'>0$ can be made arbitrarily large by taking $c>0$ large enough.

*Note that $\ln t<0$ for $t\in(0,1)$.

Can you give me feedbacks about my proof? Is it logically correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems fine. One nitpick: in the step where you divide both sides by $\ln a_n$, this only holds when $a_n > 1$. But this is true for sufficiently large $n$, which is all you really need for this proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems fine. One nitpick: in the step where you divide both sides by $\ln a_n$, this only holds when $a_n > 1$. But this is true for sufficiently large $n$, which is all you really need for this proof.