# Does $\frac{a_n}{\ln a_n}\to+\infty$ if $a_n\to+\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4147015/proof-verification-basic-calculus). Let $a_n$ be a sequence.

It is known that if $a_n=n$, then $\frac{a_n}{\ln a_n}=\frac{n}{\ln n}\to+\infty$ as $n\to+\infty$. Does the same hold for arbitrary positive real sequence $a_n$ diverging to infinity?

Is there any positive sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n\to+\infty$ and $\frac{a_n}{\ln a_n}$ does not diverges to infinity?

My intuition says that logarithm will only slow the growth of $a_n$.

Comment: $\frac{x}{\ln x} \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ over the real numbers, so yes this will hold for any sequence $a_n$ that tends to $\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{x}{\ln x} \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ over the real numbers, so yes this will hold for any sequence $a_n$ that tends to $\infty$.